# android widget refresh manually

Tags: android, widget

I have wrote a widget and it will update the content every two hours automatically according to my configuration. But how to refresh it manually by press a button in the widget. Thanks your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put one button in `layout_wid.xml` file.

in `onUpdate()` you have to find the id of your button.and put click event to refresh your widget

```
Intent imageview2Intent= new Intent(context, WatchWidget.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, imageview2Intent,0);         
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);
```

you try this way.

Comment: This actually works, and is the correct way to achieve this if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call invalidate() on the control.  See Drawing on [this page.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

```
class myActivity extends Activity{
    MyButton myButton = null;
...
onCreate(){
    myButton = findViewById(...); 
...
myMethodWhereIWantToRefreshMyButton(){
    myButton.invalidate();
```

Comment: can you elaborate more as I have no idea how to do this, many thanks!

Comment: sorry that what i mean is refresh the widgets manually by press a button which is in the widget, not in the activity.....

Comment: then call `myControl.invalidate()` within the `onClick` of that button.